# HERE API with GeoWebCache

Tags: here-api, geoserver

I am going to use HERE Map Tile API for one of my geo spatial related project. I have previously used GeoWebCache for caching tiles images for other project but not sure whether HERE Map Tile API provide TMS (Tile Map Server) protocol or GeoWebCache supports API style caching

Answer (score 1):

Here does not provide TMS, in the documentation it is mentioned that they provide only support for web mercator projection and the API associated with that with zoom level, x,y. But there are some resources you can read to convert between slippy kind of tilename and TMS. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS.